# Setting constraint so that new value in "Table A" must already exist in "Table B", else return error?

Tags: postgresql, sql, table, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to set up some kind of constraint so that I can only enter values in "Table A", if that value exists in "Table B".

I want this to act sort of like a selection list, where there are only a few values that exist in "Table B", which then restricts the values that can be entered into "Table A". (Kind of like a drop down list/ selection list)

I'm using pgAdmin 4 to access a PostGIS DB

Comment: As this is a pure SQL question, [dba.se] would be a better SE site to research this topic.